# The argument type 'Map<String, Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-packages

Dart Language

```
void main() {
  var marks = <String, Object>{
    'Name': 'Mathew',
    'Subject': {'Maths': '56', 'Science': '46', 'English': '45'}
  };
}
```

With List

```
void main() {
  var marks = <String, Object>[
    'Name': 'Mathew',
    'Subject': {'Maths': '56', 'Science': '46', 'English': '45'}
  ];
}
```

How to Access The Value of English I Tried But Cant Able to Get What was the Error

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Better to just make a data class:

```
void main() {
  final Marks marks = Marks("Mathew", {'Maths': '56', 'Science': '46', 'English': '45'});
  print(marks.subjects["English"]);
}

class Marks {
  final String name; 
  final Map<String, String> subjects;
  Marks(this.name, this.subjects);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Map marks = {
    'Name': 'Mathew',
    'Subject': {'Maths': '56', 'Science': '46', 'English': '45'}
  };

marks["Subject"]["English"]; // that gives 45
marks["Name"]; // Mathew
```